# Question on the modulus character of classical p-adic group

Tags: algebraic-groups, p-adic-groups

$\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}\DeclareMathOperator\Sp{Sp}$It is well known for the formula of the computation of modulus character of general linear groups. For example, for the standard Borel subgroup $B$ of $\GL_n$, the modulus character $\delta_B$ over the maximal torus $T$ is calculated by  $\delta_B(a_1,\cdots,a_n)=|a_1|^{1-n}|a_2|^{3-n}\cdots |a_n|^{n-1}$ (see page 5 in [these lecture notes](http://www.math.iitb.ac.in/%7Edprasad/ictp2.pdf)).

But it seems that there is no such formula for classical groups like orthogonal or symplectic groups.

More precisely, let $\Sp(2n)$ be the isometry group of some $2n$-dimensional symplectic space $W$ over a $p$-adic local field $F$. Let $P_k$ is a standard parabolic subgroup of $\Sp(2n)$ whose Levi subgroup $M_k$ is isomorphic to $\GL_k \times \Sp(2n-2k)$.

I am wondering the exact formula of the modulus character $\delta_{P_k}$ of $\Sp(2n)$ restricted to $M_k$.

I guess if we write an element of $M$ as $(a,x)\in \GL_k \times \Sp(2n-2k)$, then $\delta_P(a,x)=|\det(a)|^s$ for some real number $s$. But I don't know the value of $s$ in terms of $k$.

Thank you for your answer in advance!

Comment: Isn’t it basically the composite of the norm with the sum of all the positive roots wrt the chosen parabolic?

Comment: @DavidLoeffler, you are right! But I cannot translate such theoretical definition into the explicit formula due to my ignorance. (describing s in terms of k) I am sorry for asking such stupid question.

Comment: Your question is very reasonable, but would be more appropriate on MathStackExchange...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have indicated in your [response](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/461178/question-on-the-modulus-character-of-classical-p-adic-group#comment1196144_461178) to @DavidLoeffler's [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/461178/question-on-the-modulus-character-of-classical-p-adic-group#comment1196138_461178) that you are just looking for an explicit formula for the sum of the roots positive with respect to a given parabolic.  This sort of concrete computation is probably more appropriate for MSE than MO, but here goes: using the standard characters $\epsilon_1, \dotsc, \epsilon_n$ of a maximal split torus in $\operatorname{Sp}_{2n}$, numbered so that all $\epsilon_i - \epsilon_{i + 1}$ for $i < n$ and $2\epsilon_n$ are positive with respect to a Borel subgroup of $\operatorname{Sp}_{2n}$ contained in the parabolic in which you are interested, and the characters of the maximal tori of $\operatorname{GL}_k$ and $\operatorname{Sp}_{2(n - k)}$ are spanned by $\epsilon_1, \dotsc, \epsilon_k$ and $\epsilon_{k + 1}, \dotsc, \epsilon_n$ respectively, we have that the roots that are positive for the parabolic (i.e., the weights on its unipotent radical) are $\epsilon_i \pm \epsilon_j$ for $i \le k < j \le n$ and $2\epsilon_i$ for $i \le k$.  The sum of these is the determinant $\epsilon_1 + \dotsb + \epsilon_k$ to the power $2(n - k) + 2$.

Comment: your answer is what I expected! Thank you very much for your kind answer! By the way, I think the power $2(n-k)+2k$ in the last sentence of your comment should be $2(n-k)+2$ because $2\epsilon_i$ is counted only once in the some for each $i\le k$.

Comment: @Andrew, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/461178/question-on-the-modulus-character-of-classical-p-adic-group/461196#comment1196301_461196), oops, yes, you are right (I had been surprised that the answer came out independent of $k$!).  I fixed it; thanks!

Comment: @LSpice How do you see $(\epsilon_1 +\cdots +\epsilon_k  )^{2(n-k)+2}$ as a character of the Levi subgroup?

Comment: @PaulBroussous, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1196311), the circular—but not facetious—answer is that I regard it as the modulus character of $P$! But, less vacuously, if we write $T = T_k \times T_{n - k}$ in a hopefully obvious way, then $\epsilon_1+ \dotsb + \epsilon_k$ on $T_k$ is the restriction of the determinant character of $\operatorname{GL}_k$ and on $T_{n - k}$ is trivial, so that we may (and must, if it is to be anything at all on the Levi) view it as the character $\det \times 1$ of $\operatorname{GL}_k \times \operatorname{Sp}_{2(n - k)}$.

Comment: @LSpice, thanks for the verification!

Comment: @LSpice Thank you Loren. In other words you compute  the restrtiction of the modulus character to a maximal split torus. This is sufficient thanks to the Cartan decomposition, and in this case the situation is even simpler since the obtained character extends to the Levi subgroup.

Comment: @PaulBroussous, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/461178/question-on-the-modulus-character-of-classical-p-adic-group/461196#comment1196407_461196), yes, that should work.  (My original comment missed that we were working over a $p$-adic field.)  I was thinking of the fact that the modulus character is actually an algebraic character, and then using the almost-direct product decomposition $G = Z(G)^\circ_\text{smooth}\cdot G_\text{der}$ of a connected, reductive group $G$ to see that the restriction of a linear character of $G$ to a maximal torus suffices to determine the character.